# Insert timestamp without prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, timestamp

Is it possible to insert a record including timestamps into the database using usual statements? I don't want to use PreparedStatements.

My current query:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('some name',1965-10-31 01:00:00.0);
```

At the moment I get the error

> om.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value...

So is there a way to put timestamps into an insert query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around the date

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES('some name', '1965-10-31 01:00:00.0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('some name','1965-10-31 01:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 INSERT INTO CUSTOMER 
 VALUES('some name',STR_TO_DATE('1965-10-31 01:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'));
```